# Does char arrays get duplicated in C after fork()?

Tags: arrays, c, char, fork

I am wondering if char arrays get duplicated after fork() is called in C.
For example, in the example below is the output:

```
The message in child is secret message
The message in parent is secret message
```

or

```
The message in child is secret message
The message in parent is empty message
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    char msg[50] = "empty message";
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid > 0) {
        wait(0);
        printf("The message in parent is %s\n", msg);
    } else {
        strcpy(msg, "secret message");
        printf("The message in child is %s\n", msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling and running the code? Or reading the documentation for `fork`?

Comment: Second para of the man page: `The child process and the parent process run in separate memory spaces.  At the time of fork() both memory spaces have the same  content.  Memory writes, file mappings (mmap(2)), and unmappings (munmap(2)) performed by one of the processes do not affect the  other.`

Comment: Generally operating system does memory page (could be 4 KB) level copy-on-write. So, from a certain point of view, they're not physically duplicated until there is change in that memory page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to answer you with a fun experiment. Here's a similar but easier version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    int *px = &x;
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid > 0) {
        wait(0);
        printf("x in parent is %d\n", *px);
    } else {
        *px = 20;
        printf("x in child is %d\n", *px);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Where I used an integer to be modified by the child process to simplify the assembly. If we compile and stop at the generated assembly ( I did it with ARM compiler which I am more comfortable with ) we can see that the value 10 is saved on the stack at `sp-16`, while the address of x is saved at `sp-24`

```
        mov     w0, 10          // x = 10
        str     w0, [sp, 16]    
        add     x0, sp, 16      // px = &x
        str     x0, [sp, 24]
```

The in the child branch we modify the value of `x` by retrieving the address from the stack, and writing a new value at that address.

```
        ldr     x0, [sp, 24]   // *px = 20;
        mov     w1, 20
        str     w1, [x0]

        ldr     x0, [sp, 24]   // Load value of x and print it with message
        ldr     w0, [x0]
        mov     w1, w0
        adrp    x0, .LC1
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:.LC1
        bl      printf
```

So the value at `sp-24` is now changed right? Then how is it possible that when the parent code is executed:

```
        ldr     x0, [sp, 24]  // Load value of x and print it with message
        ldr     w0, [x0]
        mov     w1, w0
        adrp    x0, .LC0
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:.LC0
        bl      printf
        b       .L3
```

We are loading from the very same address, but we still get a value of `10`?

```
x in child is 20
x in parent is 10
```

The answer, as pointed out in the comments, is that each process has its own address space. The address space contains the stack, the heap, the mapped pages etc.. However, upon forks, the address spaces are exactly the same, hence why we can load `x` from the very same address in both cases.